# Make Translation Func Map in Go Have "Repeat" Keys Without Being Too Repetitive or Inefficient

Tags: go, data-structures, localization, translation, translate

I wanna make a go func with a data structure that lets me feed in a string and a desired language and get a translation out where each translation is connected to the others somehow.

This is what I want:

```golang
translateKeyword("es-US", "mathe") // output is "matemáticas"
translateKeyword("en-US", "matemáticas") // output is "math"
translateKeyword("de-DE", "math") // output is "mathe"
```

I already made a func in go where if you give an English word and a desired language, you get a translated output.

```golang
func translateKeyword(lang, keyword string) string {
  keywordDictionary := map[string]map[string]string{
    "home": {
      "en-US": "home",
      "es-US": "inicio",
      "de-DE": "start",
    },
    "about": {
      "en-US": "about",
      "es-US": "conóceme",
      "de-DE": "über",
    },
    // more....
  }

  translation, ok := keywordDictionary[keyword][lang]
  if ok {
    return translation
  }
  return keyword
}
translateKeyword("de-DE", "about") // output is "über" 
translateKeyword("es-US", "über") // output is "über" :(
```

You can also put a nested loop underneath to find whatever keyword you inserted to find the English word then just go through the map normally. You can also just repeat the keys over and over again so that Spanish and German each become the keys, but there has to be a better way than that.

What I really want though is to find a simple way to make any translation work as the key. I wanna find a way to do without having to make an ugly, inefficient loop at the bottom or having to scatter all my translations away from each other in case I want to add or delete a new set easily. What can I do to make my life easier?

Answer (score 1):

Given the input you already have you can build the dictionary you want, e.g.:

```golang
func build_dict(in map[string]map[string]string) (out map[string]map[string]string) {
    out = make(map[string]map[string]string)
    for _, m := range in {
        for l1, w1 := range m {
            if out[l1] == nil {
                out[l1] = make(map[string]string)
            }
            for _, w2 := range m {
                out[l1][w2] = w1
            }
        }
    }
    return out
}
```

Then you can do

```golang
var dictionary = build_dict(map[string]map[string]string{
    "home": {
        "en-US": "home",
        "es-US": "inicio",
        "de-DE": "start",
    },
    // ...
})
```

And your function can be updated to:

```golang
func translateKeyword(lang, kw string) string {
    x, ok := dictionary[lang][kw]
    if ok {
        return x
    }
    return "<unknown>"
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/9iIlAzLpwow

---

As you can see the `build_dict` function doesn't need the root key in the map, so you could achieve the same thing with just a slice of maps, i.e.

```golang
[]map[string]string{{
    "en-US": "math",
    "es-US": "matemáticas",
    "de-DE": "mathe",
}, {
    "en-US": "about",
    "es-US": "conóceme",
    "de-DE": "über",
}}
```

Comment: So is building a megamap I never have to see or code by hand the easiest way to go then? Do I need to worry about these loops taking too many resources or anything if I'm translating a lot?

Comment: @acsquared it is the easiest I can come up with. Whether you need to worry or not depends on the potential size of the dictionary and the resources available on the target machine (i.e., the host on which the application is supposed to run).